# Finding unique/new values among an existing dataset by date with mysql by data import date

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, unique, date-range

Our mysql database handles warehousing and quarterly updates of chemical compounds. We are interested in finding unique compounds that are in the most recent quarterly upload - so compounds (ChemIDs) that have never before been seen.

I've tried some code below using date ranges I found on digging through similar questions/solutions, but haven't been able to get it to work for my application. Here is my Attempt 1 that returns NULL or with variations times out (working with like 13M rows in ChemCaseReports).

Note the true *latest* `ImportDate` (datetime type) was '2012-06-12 05:58:16'.

**Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ChemID
FROM Chem_CaseReports a 
WHERE a.ImportDate = '2012-06-12 05:58:16'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT * FROM Chem_CaseReports b 
 WHERE a.ChemID = b.ChemID
 AND b.ImportDate <= '2012-06-12 05:58:16'
)
```

Is the * in the subquery necessary to avoid ambiguity between ChemID.a and .b? Do I need to add a GROUP BY or HAVING Clause OR initially supply an aggregate argument like GROUP_CONCAT in my initial select.

I have a math learning disability so the problem could be as simple as a flipped gt, eq or lt sign with my datetimes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, all you need changing is the `<=` to `<`

**Rationale**

Your original `NOT EXISTS` using `<=` *included* all records you needed to retain.

**The statement then becomes**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ChemID
FROM Chem_CaseReports a 
WHERE a.ImportDate = '2012-06-12 05:58:16'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT * FROM Chem_CaseReports b 
 WHERE a.ChemID = b.ChemID
 AND b.ImportDate < '2012-06-12 05:58:16'
)
```

Comment: +1 - thanks I am trying this now, I do have another table called ChemMaster which has all unique ChemIDs (no added dates of course). My problem is my EXPLAIN is a ref and an ALL with WHERES for both and 14.6 (no key/index) and x 22 rows. Might I try to add a join for the ChemMaster table with the ChemIDs onto the case reports as it does provide an index fpr ChemID of len 1. A newb with this stuff but just trying to speed it up - it runs forever with no output.

Comment: @cerd - Can you add covering index on `(ImportDate, ChemID)`?

Comment: so `ADD INDEX (ImportDate, ChemdID);` - Would I need to drop an existing BTREE index for ChemID?

Comment: @cerd - No *(3 more to go...)*

Comment: @cerd - Thanks for accepting the answer but can we assume that the covering indexed helped?

Comment: Your post after my add index code was either chopped off or obscured, I couldn't really understand. Could you provide a code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: @cerd - No it wasn't. My answer to your question was just 'No' but SO doesn't allow comments that short *(and shows how many more characters you have to type)* <vbg>

Comment: Could you help me with code to add covered indexes? I researched covering indexes but could not find a clear solution.